# There is any play/App store app available that only give the performance of specified of app?

Tags: manual-testing, load-testing, performance-testing, mobile-applications

Can we do manually performance testing for mobile application? There is any play/App store app available that only give the performance of specified of app. So that we can record the performance of that app only.
M2 monitor app that will give performance about specified and it is generating report also. What are the best apps to do performance testing in Android and Iphone?

Comment: *So that we can record the performance of that app only* what do you mean when say *performance*? What is the measure?

Answer (score 0):

Sharing some important parameters that should be measured while doing performance testing for mobile app

1. Most important parameter is the time taken by app to start up.
2. Consumption of battery life taken by your mobile app.
3. Memory consumption by an app
4. Usage with other Applications
5. How app is handle while running in the background

Some of the commonly used tools in software testing company are given below:

For Android devices: Robotium

For iOS devices: Automator

Answer (score 0):

When you are saying performance testing of an app, I'm assuming you are interested in the client-side performance of the mobile application.**[Appachhi](https://appachhi.com/)** provides a way to do such type of testing. I have not used it beyond POC long ago, but it looked promising to me. Here is the [Link](https://v2.appachhi.com/testReports/detailReportView/54935/90099/482c90ff97eace9d3ff38474f41fcf74) to sample result. It supports different devices against which you can test performance of your application.

[image]